How to process the data as Chunks using Ni-Fi?
My source dataset is Postgres, where I fetch data using Ni-Fi and load the data into another database using Ni-Fi. I am have the huge amounts of data in the source table, and I need to process them in small chunks. I am facing issues while processing data in chunks and needs someone's assistance. Please let me know how we can proceed.
The complete optimized flow.

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you use record-based processors downstream you shouldn't have trouble processing data, even a full ResultSet. Having said that, make sure you don't leave the Fetch Size property set to zero or the Postgres driver will fetch the entire ResultSet into memory. I recommend trying 1000 for Fetch Size, if that seems slow or the number of returned rows is large you could try 5000 or 10000.
